# Docker/ArangoDB then acces Web Arango

Tags: docker, web, arangodb

I would like to finish my installation with Docker/ArangoDB, but I find somes errors in Arangosh :

1. I install Docker CE;
2. I use this code to simplify installation and avoid manager installation :
   `sudo docker volume create arangodb3`
   `sudo docker stop arangodb-instance`
   `sudo docker run -d \ -e ARANGO_NO_AUTH=1 \ -p 8529:8529 \-v arangodb3:/var/lib/arangodb3 \ --name arangodb-instance \ arangodb/arangodb:3.4.9`

### `sudo docker exec -it arangodb-instance arangosh`

3)ARANGOSH this my errors for :

Command-line history will be persisted when the shell is exited.
Connected to ArangoDB 'http+tcp://127.0.0.1:8529' version: 3.4.9 [SINGLE, server], database: '_system', username: 'root'

Type 'tutorial' for a tutorial or 'help' to see common examples
127.0.0.1:8529@_system> `db._createDatabase("testdb");`
true

MY ERRORS :
127.0.0.1:8529@_system> users.save("testuser@localhost", "dbuserpassword");
JavaScript exception: ReferenceError: users is not defined
!users.save("testuser@localhost", "dbuserpassword");
!^
stacktrace: ReferenceError: users is not defined
at :1:1

127.0.0.1:8529@_system>
127.0.0.1:8529@_system> users.grantDatabase("testuser@example", "testdb");
JavaScript exception: ReferenceError: users is not defined
!users.grantDatabase("testuser@example", "testdb");
!^
stacktrace: ReferenceError: users is not defined
at :1:1

127.0.0.1:8529@_system>

I just to use the command-lines:
`db._dropDatabase("testdb");`
`sudo vim /etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf`
`#endpoint = tcp://127.0.0.1:8529`
`endpoint = tcp://192.168.10.11:8529`
`sudo systemctl restart arangodb3`
`sudo ufw allow proto tcp from any to any port 8529`

To have access in WEB dashboard of ArangoDB.

Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have access to the `users` object, you first need to import it a la:

```
users = require('@arangodb/users');
users.save('JohnSmith', 'mypassword');
```

Source: [Managing Users in the ArangoDB Shell](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/administration-managing-users-in-arangosh.html)